# Why do my public read-only properties in a class not show up??? (visual studio 2019)

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, properties, visual-studio-2019

This is using VB and windows forms (ugh) on visual studio 2019 :D

Ok so: I've made a class in a class library called FoodWeb, and I need to use a public read-only property thingy to use the variable in another program I'm doing.
It's called startingNodeLocation and it looks like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property startingNodeLocations As Organism()
    Get
        Return listOfOrganismStartingNodeLocation
    End Get
End Property
```

Organism is another class btw

The thing I'm trying to return is an array of organism

But for some reason, it keeps saying on the other program that startingNodeLocation is not a property of FoodWeb?

This is the line I've written in the main program (aka not the class library)

```
For i = 0 To TotalSizeOfFoodweb_Game - 1
            nodesList(i).listOfOrganismsCurrentlyAtThisNode(i) = currentfoodweb.startingNodeLocation
Next
```

[image: And this is the error message it comes up with]

I'm just a little confused on why it isn't working??
It works with other public read-only properties, such as this one

```
Public ReadOnly Property web() As Graph
    Get
        Return myWeb
    End Get
End Property
```

I know it's probably a stupid mistake, but I've been stuck here for ages

Please be patient with me because I'm kinda a beginner

Thanks in advance for all the help!!!!

Comment: what is the type of `nodesList(i)`?

Comment: *"It's called startingNodeLocation"*. No it isn't, and that is the problem. Look at the code and see what it's name actually is.

Comment: @jmcilhinney that was a typo in the question aha, it's still giving me the error message, but thank u anyway!!!!

Comment: @T.S. It's a list of lots of another little class called PictureBoxNode in the main code I forgot to mention, listOfOrganismsCurrentlyAtThisNode(i) is an array of organisms (aka the same type as startingNodeLocation) and it's a variable of the PictureBoxNode at nodesList(i). I hope that answered your question, sorry if I've confused you!!

Comment: There's obviously something going on here that you haven't shown us so show us all that's relevant. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you have to create new projects that contain only the relevant code to do so then so be it. That's software development. In fact, you should have already done that for yourself before posting here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm sorry, this is my first time asking a question here so I didn't mean to upset you. I just wasn't sure what code I should put in or what I should do. I'll try it in a new project like you suggested. Sorry again if I broke any community rules or anything, I'm trying my best :'(

Comment: @printpls we need more related code to make a test.Or you can share your whole code here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a library and editing it in the same solution, right click the library and clean it, then rebuild that library so your project that you are working on can become aware of the library’s changes in the metadata. You might also have to clean and rebuild your current project.

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't work: I think I will just give up and use a public variable for now, seeing as this is never gonna be actually used- it's just an NEA for my A-Level compsci. But another question real quick: what does cleaning the solution do??

Comment: Cleaning the solution cleans your build directories of old binaries that may be stuck there. Also are you manually referencing the library from a different location from the build directory of the library? Just curious.

Comment: Uhhm I don't really know what any of that means, but the library is in a different location, and I had to do the whole 'Imports GraphsAndOrganismsLibrary' thing? Sorry if that's not what you're asking ahha!